# Is it possible to access active directory without credentials in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory

I want to check the username is exists in Active directory or not. Once the user clicks login button, I will get the system logged in username at run time and wants to check that user name in active directory. Here, no password would be provided at any point. Is this scenario is possible with C#?

Comment: What exactly you want to check?

Comment: I want to check that user exists in intranet domain active directory or not. But I will not provide password.

Comment: Are you referring to Windows authentication? that does not need a password to login to.